# Elasticsearch random slow queries troubleshooting

Tags: performance, elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

I moved my data from a Elasticsearch cluster to another with powerful hardware
(4 nodes / 2CPU 8GB RAM each one with 4GB on JVM per machine // old cluster had 3 nodes with 1 cpu each one and 2GB on JVM per machine)
but I am randomly experiencing some very slow query responses that I didn't have on the old cluster.

Same ES version on both nodes 6.8.14 and same document numbers / shards
(62GB data / 106 million documents).

Launching the queries from kibana using the profiler on the new cluster
is showing that  most of the time is spent in this phase :

```
            "collector" : [
          {
            "name" : "CancellableCollector",
            "reason" : "search_cancelled",
            "time_in_nanos" : 5777066437,
            "children" : [
              {
                "name" : "MultiCollector",
                "reason" : "search_multi",
                "time_in_nanos" : 5756203807,
                "children" : [
                  {
                    "name" : "SimpleTopScoreDocCollector",
                    "reason" : "search_top_hits",
                    "time_in_nanos" : 747674917
                  },
                  {
                    "name" : "MultiBucketCollector: [[min_price, max_price, in_stock, out_of_stock, category, agg_h, mdata, agg_att, agg_f]]",
                    "reason" : "aggregation",
                    "time_in_nanos" : 4966026553
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
```

CPU usage per node is pretty low (5/10%) and load average is OK (0.50)

Launching the same query again in short time lowers the response from 8 sec to 0.4 sec (due to ES caching I guess), also removing the "aggs" part from the query seems to fix the issue so poor performance is actually during the aggregators phase.

Anyway I do not understand why this slowdown occurs only on the new "better" cluster... how can I optimize the performance or better troubleshoot ?

Comment: Can you share your query and the mapping of your index maybe?

Comment: Issue was happening randomly with every query containing aggregations, so it was not a matter of a specific query. However after a day performance seems greatly improved so I think of some Elastic post-indexing background operation causing workload - could it make sense ? All indexes data were migrated yesterday with multielasticdump tool.

Comment: Of course, if there is a heavy indexing load while you run queries, the search performance can be impacted. But without more information, it's hard to make any conclusions.